# How to parse a date string with microseconds

Tags: datetime, d3.js

I have some datetime string e.g.

```
"2017-10-29T02:54:03.125983+00:00"
"2017-10-29T02:09:22.1453833+00:00"
```

with 6 or 7 digital length milliseconds, how can I parse it to date object in d3 javascript language? I have tried

```
d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
```

but failed, it returns null

Comment: May be `125983` is in microseconds think you are mistaking it for milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

What you have is not a *long millisecond*<sup>✻</sup>: that is a **microsecond**.

There is a specifier in D3 for microseconds since D3 v4 (see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/issues/24)). To parse microseconds, use `"f"`. According to the API:

> %f - microseconds as a decimal number [000000, 999999].

Here is a demo with your string (don't look at the Stack snippet console, click "Run code snippet" and open your browser console to see the actual date):

```js
var date = "2017-10-29T02:54:03.125983+00:00";
var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z"); 
console.log(parser(date))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
```

**Three observations**:

1. Contrary to what the own API says, `"f"` will **not** work with the default bundle. You have to reference the standalone time microlibrary (have a look at my demo above to see the URL). Lets prove it:

```js
var date = "2017-10-29T02:09:22.145383+00:00";
var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z"); 
console.log(parser(date))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

2. Remove that `"Z"`. It should be `"%Z"` instead. As the API says, *"Note that the literal Z here is different from the time zone offset directive %Z"*;
3. There is no microsecond with 7 digits. It has to be 6 digits.

<sup>✻</sup> Title edited.

Comment: D3 indeed is very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to parse a date object which is incorrect, I think you want to format the date object.

Instead of:

```
d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
```

try this:

```
d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
```