# D3v4: d3.timeParse fails with UNIX epoch seconds (%s)

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

My dataset includes UNIX timestamps, such as "1509392160". I can't seem to parse those using `d3.timeParse("%s")`, which returns null.

Checking the reverse process with `d3.timeFormat` fails me as well. The official example and all other format strings work:

```
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
formatTime(new Date); // -> "June 30, 2015"
```

However, formatting to UNIX (milli)seconds just returns "s" or "Q" for "%s" and "%Q":

```
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%s");
formatTime(new Date); // -> "s"
```

Using D3 v4.11.0 btw. 
What am I missing?

Comment: As the answer below explains, the default bundle will not work with some specifiers. For instance, have a look at my answer here, regarding `"f"`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010168/5768908

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran this code with only the d3-time-format module and had no problems:

```js
var parse = d3.timeParse("%s");
var time = parse(1509392160);

console.log(time);

var format = d3.timeFormat("%s");
time = format(Date.now());

console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
```

However, as you have found out, this does not work with d3 v4.11 (nor does it work with any other version of d3 v4). It appears that d3-time-format only recently added functionality to support parsing UNIX timestamps, and was [released on October 9, 2017](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/releases/tag/v2.1.0).

The "%s" and "%Q" selectors were added in the most recent release along with "%f", "%u", and "%V", these other ones also appear to not work in v4.11:

```js
console.log(d3.timeParse("%u")(1));  // day of week
console.log(d3.timeParse("%V")(25)); // week of year
console.log(d3.timeParse("%f")(100));// microseconds

console.log("For Comparison, %Y:");
console.log(d3.timeParse("%Y")(2017)); // Year
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Meanwhile, it appears that d3 v4.11 was [released on October 3rd, 2017](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.11.0). It would appear that the most recent d3 core library is therefore outdated in this respect. I would imagine that an updated version will be available shortly.

Though you should be able to use both the core library for everything else and the module for time formatting/parsing to get the desired functionality (until an update appears anyways):

```js
var parse = d3.timeParse("%Q");
var time = parse(1509392160);

d3.select("body").append("p")
  .html(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The same problem (default bundle vs. standalone microlibrary) happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010168/5768908

Comment: Totally missed that question (and answer), might have saved me a bit of head scratching.

Comment: Andrew, check the edit in my answer (and thanks for correcting the "U").

Comment: That's an edit that would probably go unnoticed by anyone else, thought I'd slip it in though just in case (wasn't worth commenting it). Good to get confirmation, I figured it would be out next release or so based on the chronology, good to have confirmation from the source.

Comment: To be completely honest, only **after** I posted the Github issue I paid attention to the release dates in your answer. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47044714/5768908), this is the problem:

D3 default (core) bundle has these specifiers in its [source code](https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js):

```
var parses = {
    "a": parseShortWeekday,
    "A": parseWeekday,
    "b": parseShortMonth,
    "B": parseMonth,
    "c": parseLocaleDateTime,
    "d": parseDayOfMonth,
    "e": parseDayOfMonth,
    "H": parseHour24,
    "I": parseHour24,
    "j": parseDayOfYear,
    "L": parseMilliseconds,
    "m": parseMonthNumber,
    "M": parseMinutes,
    "p": parsePeriod,
    "S": parseSeconds,
    "U": parseWeekNumberSunday,
    "w": parseWeekdayNumber,
    "W": parseWeekNumberMonday,
    "x": parseLocaleDate,
    "X": parseLocaleTime,
    "y": parseYear,
    "Y": parseFullYear,
    "Z": parseZone,
    "%": parseLiteralPercent
};
```

As you can see, if you compare this with the [complete list here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format), it's missing all these:

- "f"
- "Q"
- "s"
- "V"
- "u"

So, the alternative for now is referencing the time standalone microlibrary:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: indeed, the default bundle doesn't have yet those new directives. This is a GitHub issue just closed by Bostock: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/issues/38

So, meanwhile, just stick with the standalone microlibrary.